# Visual Studio - Source Control Explorer for TFS - how to view which changeset is your local copy

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I use Visual Studio 16.4.2 (2019) and TFS.
How to check "where" is my local copy of code (whick changeset I have locally)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS workspace does not contain a property to track differences between local and server changeset versions. As workaround:

1. You can compare you local and server root folders:

[image]

[image]

2. Just periodically update your workspace

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the changeset number in your workspace, you can use the following [history command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/history-command?view=azure-devops) from the root (top) of your workspace:

`tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W`

Check the follow blog for more information of this command:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2009/01/26/how-to-determine-the-latest-changeset-in-your-workspace/